# Definition of $Z/\left<n\right>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I don't really understand the notation here, $\left<n\right>$ seems to be the principal ideal generated by n, how come one define $Z/\left<n\right>=Z+\left<n\right>$?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment by accident ... I explained that $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ since $\langle n \rangle$ is the subadditive group of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing all the multiples of $n$, namely $n \mathbb{Z}$. And note that this is an equality, not just an isomorphism. Also the equality at the end is false. The LHS has finite order (and can be represented by $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$) while the RHS is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by $\mathbb{Z}+ \langle n \rangle$ since strictly speaking, $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} + \langle n \rangle$ as sets, so I think maybe some notation is getting mixed up. As mentioned in the comments,
$$
\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle = \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}
$$
by definition and can be thought of as a set of [cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset),
$$
\lbrace m + n\mathbb{Z} \; | \; 0 \leq m < n \rbrace = \mathbb{Z}_n
$$
Or, the set of equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ under the relation that
$$
a \sim b\quad \text{iff}\quad a-b \equiv 0 \mod n
$$
If this is not helpful or clear, let me know and I can edit or delete.

Comment: I'm reading this in the context of ring, the book mentions the First Ring Isomorphism theorem, and $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle \sim Z_n$, where n is the additive order
of 1.  Will the definition of the operator "/" be the same here?

Comment: Yes, equivalence is still equivalence modulo $n$.

Comment: In rings theory, the operator "/" denotes an algebraic quotient. Making a quotient of a ring will create a new ring, and the "object" you use as denominator will define which elements of the "quotiented" ring are considered to be the same in the new one. Of course you can only make the quotient by particular sets to preserve the ring structure while making a quotient.